# TFS 2018 Update 2 Failure using VSTS Symbol Server

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-artifacts

We just updated to TFS 2018 Update 2, and have mostly found it to work well. However, there's one problem I'm trying to chase down.

When we enable Version 2.* of the Push Symbols Path, to allow symbols to be pushed to a local Package Management instance, we get this error in the logs.

> 2018-08-28T20:44:52.1190209Z ##[section]Starting: Publish symbols path: 
>   2018-08-28T20:44:52.1199163Z ==============================================================================
>   2018-08-28T20:44:52.1199425Z Task         : Index Sources & Publish Symbols
>   2018-08-28T20:44:52.1199672Z Description  : Index your source code and publish symbols to a file share or Visual Studio Team Services Symbol Server
>   2018-08-28T20:44:52.1199914Z Version      : 2.0.7
>   2018-08-28T20:44:52.1200096Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
>   2018-08-28T20:44:52.1200457Z Help         : See [more information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613722) on how to use this task. The Visual Studio Team Services Symbol Server is in public preview. See [these instructions](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=846265) on how to use Symbol Server in VSTS.
>   2018-08-28T20:44:52.1201576Z ==============================================================================
>   2018-08-28T20:44:54.3255523Z Found 5 files.
>   2018-08-28T20:44:57.3859527Z ##[command]"E:\BuildAgent.126.002_work_tasks\PublishSymbols_0675668a-7bba-4ccb-901d-5ad6554ca653\2.0.7\pdbstr.exe" -w -p:"E:\BuildAgent.126.002_work\36\s\SidesTransactionFileCopier\SidesTransactionFileCopier\SidesTransactionFileCopier\bin\Release\SidesTransactionFileCopier.pdb" -i:"C:\Users\TfsBuild\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp18E7.tmp" -s:srcsrv
>   2018-08-28T20:44:57.9176919Z ##[command]"E:\BuildAgent.126.002_work_tasks\PublishSymbols_0675668a-7bba-4ccb-901d-5ad6554ca653\2.0.7\pdbstr.exe" -w -p:"C:\Users\TfsBuild\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1B0C.tmp" -i:"C:\Users\TfsBuild\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1B0B.tmp" -s:srcsrv
>   2018-08-28T20:44:58.0030036Z ##[command]"E:\BuildAgent.126.002_work_tasks\PublishSymbols_0675668a-7bba-4ccb-901d-5ad6554ca653\2.0.7\pdbstr.exe" -w -p:"C:\Users\TfsBuild\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1B5C.tmp" -i:"C:\Users\TfsBuild\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1B5B.tmp" -s:srcsrv
>   2018-08-28T20:44:58.1041103Z ##[command]"E:\BuildAgent.126.002_work_tasks\PublishSymbols_0675668a-7bba-4ccb-901d-5ad6554ca653\2.0.7\pdbstr.exe" -w -p:"C:\Users\TfsBuild\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1BCB.tmp" -i:"C:\Users\TfsBuild\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1BCA.tmp" -s:srcsrv
>   2018-08-28T20:44:58.1696916Z ##[command]"E:\BuildAgent.126.002_work_tasks\PublishSymbols_0675668a-7bba-4ccb-901d-5ad6554ca653\2.0.7\pdbstr.exe" -w -p:"E:\BuildAgent.126.002_work\36\s\TumbleWeedAccountReportGenerator\TumbleWeedAccountReportGenerator\bin\Release\TumbleWeedAccountReportGenerator.pdb" -i:"C:\Users\TfsBuild\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1C0B.tmp" -s:srcsrv
>   2018-08-28T20:44:58.2574932Z Symbol Request Name = catboy project/catboyproject od deployment/20180828.1/3468/44306d45-27b3-4473-ba5e-c3a045d4aca5
>   2018-08-28T20:44:58.8450948Z StatusCode 'NotFound' returned on account https://tfs.cdle.int/tfs/UIIntegratedCollection
>   2018-08-28T20:44:58.9649875Z ##[error]The VSTS Symbol Server feature is not enabled for this account. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=846265 for instructions on how to enable it.

We have followed the steps in the hyperlink, and it seems all users either have a VS Enterprise account or have a free license assigned to them.

Any clue as to what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

On-prem TFS does not support using a package management feed as a symbol server. You will have to publish the symbols to a UNC path.

Refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/symbols/?view=vsts), emphasis mine:

> A symbol server is available with Package Management **in VSTS** and works best with Visual Studio 2017.4 and newer. **Team Foundation Server users** and users without the Package Management extension can publish symbols to a file share using this task.

Comment: Hi. I have just read your answer closer. Quotation: "Team Foundation Servers and Users Without the Package Management Extension **can** publish symbols to a file share using this task." This implies to me that you have a choice, not that you must. Can you direct me to where you're getting the answer that you must use a file share rather than a package management feed? 

Thank you.

Comment: @user3294554 read the documentation at the link I posted. There's a Q&A section at the bottom that says what the options are for on prem TFS users.